# Как загрузить карту после выполнения скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery, яндекс-карты

Надо что бы сначала выполнился скрипт ресайза блока, а потом подгрузилась карта.

А в итоге все наоборот, сначала грузится карта, после ресайзится блок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пример тут: codepen.io/inkshio/pen/KBXjgx

Comment: `setTimeout()`  подойдёт ?

Comment: Без него бы обойтись.

Comment: Вот два примера: [Создание карты по требованию](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/request_map?from=SO) и [Изменение размера карты вместе с блоком](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/fillcontainer?from=SO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опция autoFitToViewport: 'always' мне помогла в этом вопросе.